# HP Proliant DL100G2 cant quick restore from recovery disc on RAID 5 array

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid

When Attempting to Restore Factory Settings (Window Server 2003) from recovery disc, on to a RAID 5 Configuration of 3 discs (note 4th disk died and has been remove and array recreated), i get the error "invalid logical drive configuration has been detected", Im fairly new to the setting up of servers from scratch, have i configured Raid incorrectly?

Adaptec AE438B
Raid 5
mirrored
932GB
256kb
write cache: disabled
build/verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recovery disk won't be able to fully deal with your after-market Adaptec controller as it assumes you've bought a HP model instead, it just won't know what to do with it.

Comment: Is there any software for an EFI boot that may help manage the array for an installation or should I go and get an actual disk of windows server and forget about the recovery system

Comment: The latter makes much more sense.

Comment: i just checked supposedly the RAID card is standard it all the models, but i cant be bothered wasting any more time, thanks for the help